# Combine numpy arrays to list if first index value is similar

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How to combine arrays inside 2D array to a list if the **first index value** is the same?

Say for example, this 2D array:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 3]
 [0 4]
 [1 1]
 [2 2]
 [3 0]
 [3 3]
 [3 4]
 [4 0]
 [4 3]
 [4 4]]
```

How will I make it to something like this?

```
[[0, 0, 3, 4], [1 1], [2 2], [3 0 3 4], [4 0 3 4]]
```

When converting from numpy to list, I need it to be optimized as there are thousands of rows on my end.

Any suggestion is much appreciated. The end goal is I want the **second index value** to be combined together.

*Also, take into consideration if ever the first index value is not in ascending order.*

Comment: The output is not a valid numpy array (unless using the object type which makes it not very useful)

Comment: @mozway I'll edit it. The output should be a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
my_list = [
    [0, 0],
    [0, 3],
    [0, 4],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 0],
    [3, 3],
    [3, 4],
    [4, 0],
    [4, 3],
    [4, 4]
    ]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i, j in my_list:
    d[i].append(j)

combined = [[i]+l for i,l in d.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


ll = [[0, 0], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 0], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 0], [4, 3], [4, 4]]
x = np.array(ll)
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
dx = df.groupby(0).apply(lambda g: g[1].tolist())
[[x[0], *x[1]] for x in zip(dx.index.tolist(), dx.values.tolist())]
```